# How to Read Rss Feed in Asp.net MVC for every 2 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, scheduled-tasks

I have method in MVC like

```
 public void ReadRss()
 {
     //Read Rss Feed in Asp.net MVC for every 2 hours
 }
```

Can I schedule above method to execute for every 2 hours.

Is this a good idea? Please show me a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: If you have to call a URL. You can use that way. [Set windows scheduler to open a webpage or the bookmark](http://superuser.com/questions/447368/set-windows-scheduler-to-open-a-webpage-or-the-bookmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web application I would go with [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) because it has a web UI to track execution of jobs and it has lots of options like recurrent jobs, delayed, one time jobs.
In your case something along these lines:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("rssurl", () => ReadRss(), Cron.Hourly);
```

docs [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html)

You'll also find in docs how to pass params.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you have chosen web project, a console application seems better fit to a scheduling logic but if you insist on web you could create a windows task that call your action URL by intervals. The second approach could be forgetting action and developing a schedule logic in asp.net code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a scheduler with quartz.net. Check out the quick start guide here: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html